# Creating a channel in specific category (the category id is should be variable) discord.py

Tags: discord.py

```py
maincategory = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=858441350667698190)
```

So here is the normal method but I want to do it by giving variable:

```py
wanted_category_id = 858441350667698190
maincategory = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=wanted_category_id)
```

but When I `print(maincategory)` it says `None` how can I do it?

Comment: How are you getting the ID of the category?

Comment: Try printing the `guild`

Answer (score 1):

Category is in fact a `CategoryChannel` object which derives from `abc.GuildChannel` which is the return type for `Guild.get_channel` function, so you can use it to your advantage and insted of getting this category like this:

```py
category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=category_id)
```

you can do this instead:
[`discord.Guild.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel)

```py
category = guild.get_channel(category_id)
```

After you get the category channel this way you can create text channel in it by doing so:
[`discord.CategoryChannel.create_text_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel.create_text_channel)

```py
await category.create_text_channel(channel_name, **options)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
category = bot.get_channel(wanted_category_id)
brand_new_channel = await category.create_text_channel(  # There's also create_voice_channel and create_stage_channel.
    channel_name,                                        # channel_name should be "general", not "#general".
    # The rest are optional.
    overwrites={                                         # Used for custom channel permissions and private channels.
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(
            send_messages=False                          # By default, members can't send messages...
        ),
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite.from_pair(
            discord.Permissions.all(),                   # But the bot has all permissions enabled...
            discord.Permissions.none()                   # And none disabled!
        )
    },
    reason='Because I can'                               # This shows up in the audit logs.
)
await brand_new_channel.send('Ooh boy! A shiny new channel!')
```

Important part:

```py
await category.create_text_channel(channel_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```py
c = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, id=ID) # Gets the category.
await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name="whatever", category=c)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across the same problem:

Common cases that causes `utils.get` or any `get_x` method to return `None` would be:

- The bot can't "see" the object
- The id passed is invalid (IDs are integers, not strings)
- The object is not in cache or the bot is not logged in.

A possible solution would be to use `fetch_x` methods which calls the API to pull the relevant object if it's in cache or not.

```py
wanted_category_id = 858441350667698190

category = await bot.fetch_channel(wanted_category_id)
```

[Bot.fetch_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.fetch_channel)